# C word pointer to a byte structure member

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

**Edit2** I was using foobar(*bar); in the example, instead of *myvar, embarassing.

**Edit** This appears to be a behavior of the Texas compiler for MSP430 microcontrollers, not a "c" thing. To clarify, the code below is compiled with code composer studio 7 for MSP430FR5969 16-bit (20-bit addressing) microcontroller using Texas LTS compiler 16.9.x. The result is the same with the STS 17.9.x. I edited the code example to make it more explicit it's not a naming thing. The microcontroller compiler does not align structure members on word boundaries unless you explicitly ask for it.

I have a structure like this:

```
struct foo_{
   uint8_t low;
   uint8_t high;
} foo;
```

And I'm trying to be clever like this:

```
void bar(){
   uint16_t * volatile myvar;
   myvar = (uint16_t *) &foo.low;
   foobar(*myvar);
}

void foobar(uint16_t value){
   printf("Value %d\n", value);
}
```

You'd expect the pointer *myvar to point to the foo.low address but it's something completely different.. Shouldn't it be perfectly valid in C if we throw portability out of the window?

**EDIT**
I have edited the code example. The unexpected behavior is a mismatch between what is shown in the debugger (that is able to show word data from an odd memory locations) and the actual processor (which will return 0xFFFF on word read from an odd address). Compiled code sometimes failing, sometimes not is caused by the structure's actual location in the FRAM memory.

Comment: from my understanding of structs this is undefined behavior since structs can be padded, maybe check sizeof(foo) and see if its not 2

Comment: Are you sure it is *completely* different?  If you look at the values (expected and actual) in hexadecimal, do you see *any* relationship?  And since throwing portability out the window resulted in an incorrect result, maybe you weren't so clever after all.

Comment: `*bar` isn’t a pointer.  Please clarify your question, preferably making an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Highly depends on the compiler and target machine. Struct is not always tightly packed (can be padded), most of the time to align to machine word boundary for ease of access.

Comment: It's a violation of strict aliasing, you should use a `union` instead. Apart from that, it seems like `bar` *should* point to `&foo.low`, but it's impossible to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: @ScottHunter yeah, no relation whatsoever. In this specific example the &foo.low resolves to 0x0000B2E6 while pointer bar contains 0x000003C2.

Comment: The missing part here is that I'm using Texas Code Composer v7 with their compiler for MSP430. It's a 16-bit microcontroller with 20-bit addressing.

Comment: @Barleyman: perhaps the fact that your struct has the same name as the variable is confusing your compiler?

Comment: I would expect at least the `low` part to be correct even if there is some padding further in the struct, (alignment is not padding). Endianness? If `bar = 0x1234` you should have `low` set to 0x34 on x86 (little endian)

Comment: @RingØ It appears this is not a "c" thing at all. I get different behavior with that code on my actual program (about 18 kB of code) and that code snipped as it is. So it's likely that the Texas TLV compiler loses the plot somewhere along the way. Not that this is very "nice" way to program. For what it's worth, compiler for a 64kB 16-bit microcontroller does *not* pad things behind your back.

Comment: *And I'm trying to be clever...*  [Clever code is bad code.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25276/why-is-cleverness-considered-harmful-in-programming-by-some-people/25281)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Casting two byte variables as a single short is not really "clever" in the sense of being hard to understand or obscure. In this case it does not work as intended, most likely due to compiler/linker optimizing things where it shouldn't. The "correct" way to do this would be to malloc() the structure but I have all of 400 bytes of heap right now..

Comment: I revised the example to make it explicit there are no naming issues.

Comment: I figured it out. It is indeed aliasing problem. The microcontroller cannot do a MOV.W instruction from an odd address and will return 0xFFFF instead. Aligning the low-byte to word address seems like an easy fix but as the registry is externally (burst) addressable, this would create a situation where the registers would be at different addresses at different times. Solutions are either babysitting the structure to make sure 2-byte values are aligned at even addresses OR perform byte-to-word or word-to-byte conversion manually.

Comment: Listen to Groo.  What you are doing breaks C's strict aliasing.  Use a union if you want to be clever like this.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Not a solution due to external access to the registry.

Comment: However, using #pragma DATA_ALIGN in Texas compiler ensures struct starts at even address which would make it a valid solution. GCC has "aligned" attribute that does the same thing. You'd still have to ensure the union does not cause padding to avoid breaking burst access to registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
The behavior is caused by the byte-address being stored in an odd memory location. The MSP430 microcontroller cannot return a word value from odd addresses and will assign 0xFFFF to the target variable. 
Some of the examples/test cases work because the structure member happens to be in an even address.

The uint8_t myconfig_rw.current_l is located (in the code compiled at this time) in memory address 0x04563, which is not word-aligned. The 
current = (USHORT *) &myconfig_rw.current_l; line generates this:

```
MOVX.A #0x04563,0x0000a(SP)
```

When I deference this to a word variable, these lines are generated

```
MOVA 0x000a(SP),R15
MOV.W @R15,0x000e(SP)
```

0x000e receives 0xFFFF instead of whatever is in address 0x04563 as the processor is unable to read word from an odd address.

Now the code composer *debugger* does not have issues with showing word values from odd addresses and will happily display expected value (0x140) in the pointer address.

To fix the issue it would be necessary either to manually arrange the two-byte values to start at even addresses or do manual conversions between words and bytes. Using an union is not a solution as the registry is externally burst read/write addressable. The register addresses could shift by one byte depending if padding is needed or not.

A partial workaround would be to define the registry structure to start at word-aligned address and document the code in hopes the "next guy" wouldn't mess with it. Converting a word to two bytes or vice versa seems much safer approach.

**OLD**
This appears to be behavior specific to the Code Composer Studio with Texas TLV 17.x compiler generating code for MSP430FR5969 16-bit microcontroller. It appears the code snippet in the question is "valid" if not very nice. When used in the actual application, results are unpredictable. Considering this snippet:

```
struct myconfig_rw_{
    uint8_t current_l;
    uint8_t current_h;
} myconfig_rw;

void PWM_Decode_Init(){

USHORT * volatile current;
current = (USHORT *) &myconfig_rw.current_l;
PWM_status.current_constant=Calculate_Current_Constant(*current, false);
}
```

*current will in fact contain the correct 16-bit value from myconfig_rw.current_l and .current_h. However the value passed to the Calculate_Current_Constant function is incorrect, function receives value 0xFFFF.

As a conclusion, you shouldn't try to be too clever for your own good with pointers.

A self-contained tiny example that will provide expected results:

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo_{
    uint8_t low;
    uint8_t high;
}foo;

/**
 * main.c
 */
void foobar(uint16_t test);

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t * volatile bar;
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    foo.low=0x10;
    foo.high=0xBB;
    bar = (uint16_t *) &foo.low;
    printf("address %p, value %x\n", bar, *bar);
    foobar(bar);
    __no_operation();
    return 0;
}

void foobar(uint16_t test){
    printf("value %x\n", test );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what was going on.  I believe I ran across something very similar to this years ago.  It was not exactly the same issue but it did have to do with the odd/even addresses. I dont think the compiler generated code that gave incorrect results, but performance was impacted.  Later on I found the explanation and needed to make sure the pointers were on even boundaries.

Comment: @dernst In texas compiler you can use #pragma DATA_ALIGN to start the struct on even address so you can be sure your given low-byte member is on an even address by arranging the members. In this case I decided discretion is the better part and reviewed code to make sure external word accesses are broken into byte operations.

Comment: @dernst Eventually I decided to implement it with byte and word members - Dealing with 16-bit signed values split into bytes became too much bother. You can still access higher/lower byte externally as it's addressed by an offset unlike internal operations which are name-based. You have to babysit the registry to make sure your word variables are word-aligned but that's them breaks.

Answer (score 2):

I think Groo most likely is right.  Below is code that works as expected.  I do not see in the question how the addresses are printed out. If you put the printf statement in main instead of bar, it will compile and run perfectly fine but give you misleading results.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct _foo{
    uint8_t low;
    uint8_t high;
} foo;

void bar(){
    uint16_t *bar;
    bar = (uint16_t *) &foo.low;
    printf("From within foo() : foo.low addr: %x, foo.high addr: %x, bar addr: %x\n", (uint32_t) &foo.low, (uint32_t)&foo.high, (uint32_t)bar);

}

main(){
    bar();
    printf("From within main(): foo.low addr: %x, foo.high addr: %x, bar addr: %x\n", (uint32_t) &foo.low, (uint32_t)&foo.high, (uint32_t)bar);
}
```

Comment: Yes, my trivial example code does in fact work as you'd expect, as long as you do remember the volatile pointer definition is "uint16_t * volatile foo", not "volatile uint16_t * foo". See my answer for a compiling code. However the code snippet from actual application does *not* work so in a non-trivial program you shouldn't expect this kind of hack to produce the result you wanted. If I do casting like this: *(uint16_t *) &foo.low; I'll end up with 0xFFFF as a result..

Comment: So what do you think is happening?  while you used the volatile keyword to influence the compiler, does the code work with optimization turned off?

Comment: volatile was just for WYSIWYG in debugger. I've raised a case with texas about it. I'm pretty sure it's a "feature". If I store the address as a variable, pass that to the function and convert it back a pointer in there it works as expeceted. But that shouldn't be exactly necessary. And before you ask, no, there's no real reason to cast the 2-byte value as a 16-bit pointer as the function only gets the value in any case. There are places where low-level functions have to manipulate that configuration structure directly, thought, which is not very nice.

Comment: Turning all optimizations off is not really an option. It's a 16MHz microcontroller and without even register optimizations (lowest level) it turns glacially slow.

Comment: I would agree that this may be an issue with Texas compiler given that you say it works by passing it through a variable instead of de-referencing prior to passing it in as a value.  I would be curious to hear what Texas has to say!

Comment: The problem appears to be caused by the processor returning 0xFFFF if you do a word-read from an odd memory location. Words are expected to be aligned in even addresses.